# How home gateway divide internet bandwidth?

Tags: home-networking, bandwidth, gateway

I have a little ADSL Modem/gateway (FritzBox), and I see that while I'm downloading from one device, all other devices can not use the Internet connection; the download bandwidth is fully used by the downloading device and no more resources are available. For example, while my computer is downloading a big file, my smartphone cannot browse.

My question is: how do these home network gateways work? Why doesn't it divide the bandwidth proportionally among the requests?

Comment: If you can add QOS to your router you can limited bandwidth so no 1 device can hog it all unless nothing else wants the internet.

Comment: Ok but usually how it works? Is it simply a Fifo queue?

Comment: How are your clients connected to your router: through Ethernet, 802.11g, 802.11n?

Comment: Really does it mean? During my test the downloader was connected with wifi(n) and the other device was wired to Lan port.

Comment: Really! The bandwidth of each connection will determine its share of the uplink bandwidth. Next this "available" bandwidth must be divided by the number of logical connections which are consuming it on each physical connection.